# conversion operator which refers to class template parameters and constexpr class members

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang, language-lawyer

```
#include <cstddef>

template <class T, std::size_t rank_>
struct  B { };

template <class T, std::size_t rank_>
struct  A {
    static constexpr auto rank = rank_;
    operator B<T, rank>() noexcept;
};

template <class T, std::size_t rank>
A<T, rank>::operator B<T, rank>() noexcept { return {}; }
```

Note that `rank_` is a class template parameter of `A` and `rank` is a compile-time constant which is a member of `A`.

1. `rank` is used in declaration of the conversion operator

   - g++ and clang compile without errors.
   - MSVC 19.20 gives `unable to match definition to an existing declaration`
2. `rank_` is used in the declaration of the conversion operator

   - declaration is changed from `operator B<T, rank>() noexcept;` to `operator B<T, rank_>() noexcept;`
   - g++ gives `no declaration matches A<T, rank>::operator B<T, rank>`
   - clang gives `out-of-line definition of operator B<type-parameter-0-0, rank> does not match any declaration in A<T, rank_>`
   - MSVC compiles without errors

---

1. Who is correct?
2. What is a portable solution to the problem?

Thanks to Artyer, changing the symbol name from `rank` to `rank_` in the operator definition fixes the problem. It could've been due to an ambiguity between the template parameter named `rank` and the class member `rank`. The compilers perform the name lookup differently.

Godbolt Link: https://godbolt.org/z/6oFdrf

Comment: Strangely it works if you change the out-of-line definition to use the name `rank_` in gcc (`template<class T, std::size_t rank_> A<T, rank_>::operator B<T, rank_>() noexcept { return {}; }`)

Comment: @Artyer bumper! It works for MSVC too but it's very weird that a changing a symbol name stopped the error. I wonder if there was a collision between the `rank` member and `rank` template parameter in the overload.

Comment: It's very likely a collision of the symbol `rank`. With the `A<T, rank>::` part the `rank` must be the template argument, since the compiler can't know the member variable yet. But with `::operator B<T, rank>()` then `rank` could be either the template argument *or* the member variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Who is correct?

Clang and GCC are correct on all accounts. The reason your changed definition becomes ill-formed is an interesting mixture of clauses. I'll name them first, then explain further.

> **[temp.local]**
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.local#7) In the definition of a member of a class template that appears
>   outside of the class template definition, the name of a member of the
>   class template hides the name of a template-parameter of any enclosing
>   class templates (but not a template-parameter of the member if the
>   member is a class or function template). [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>   struct B { /* ... */ };
>   typedef void C;
>   void f();
>   template<class U> void g(U);
> };
>
> template<class B> void A<B>::f() {
>   B b;              // A's B, not the template parameter
> }
>
> template<class B> template<class C> void A<B>::g(C) {
>   B b;              // A's B, not the template parameter
>   C c;              // the template parameter C, not A's C
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]
>
> **[temp.over.link]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.over.link#4) When an expression that references a template parameter is used
>   in the function parameter list or the return type in the declaration
>   of a function template, the expression that references the template
>   parameter is part of the signature of the function template. This is
>   necessary to permit a declaration of a function template in one
>   translation unit to be linked with another declaration of the function
>   template in another translation unit and, conversely, to ensure that
>   function templates that are intended to be distinct are not linked
>   with one another. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template <int I, int J> A<I+J> f(A<I>, A<J>);   // #1
> template <int K, int L> A<K+L> f(A<K>, A<L>);   // same as #1
> template <int I, int J> A<I-J> f(A<I>, A<J>);   // different from #1
> ```
>
> — end example ] [ Note: Most expressions that use template parameters
>   use non-type template parameters, but it is possible for an expression
>   to reference a type parameter. For example, a template type parameter
>   can be used in the sizeof operator.  — end note ]

So in the *declaration* of `opertor B<T, rank>`, the id-expression `rank` (`A<T, rank_>::rank`) is part of the signature of the operator, because it is used in the return type (a conversion operator's return type is implicitly given as part of its name), and it references a template parameter.

When you changed `operator B<T, rank>() noexcept;` to `operator B<T, rank_>() noexcept;`, you changed the operator's signature! Now the out of class definition didn't match, because you still try to use the id-experssion `rank` in the signature, given the class member hides the template parameter after the `::`.

```
template <class T, std::size_t rank>
A<T, rank>::operator B<T, rank>() noexcept { return {}; }
                        // ^- This is the member of A, not the name 
                        //    of the parameter above it
```

> What is a portable solution to the problem?

Not using the `rank` member as a template argument or parameter name, and instead opting for `rank_` everywhere, allows the three compilers in your question to accept the code.